Twillio: sending otp using whatsapp
I am trying to use twillio to send otp to users, put the process is hard to configure.
this is my cUrl
curl --location 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountID/Messages.json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Token' \
--data-urlencode 'To=whatsapp:+20121234566' \
--data-urlencode 'From=whatsapp:+201022009062' \
--data-urlencode 'ForceDelivery=true' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=1234 s your verification code. For your security, do not share this code.' \
--data-urlencode '='

all I get a response with status 201 63106 failed to send freeform message
and if added ConentSid I get failed with error 21619
any help please?
